# Use SSL module with twisted instead of Pyopenssl

Tags: python, twisted, pyopenssl

I currently have a twisted webapp which relies on pyopenssl. We are trying to move away from pyopenssl, which is a 3rd party dependency, in favour of the built in SSL module. Would anyone know if this is possible with twisted?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @lambdaeagle. What have you tried so far? Please have a look, on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Twisted only supports TLS using pyOpenSSL.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) instead of twisted, which is also a 3rd party dependency.

It is probably easier for you to rewrite your app as it is for twisted to replace pyOpenSSL with the standard library version as they are incompatible implementations.

PyOpenSSL has a lot more functionality.

Rewriting the tests alone would take ages.